# Re format a python string after splitting

Tags: python

I have string like "week32_Aug_24_2016".
I want to change this string like "week32_2016_Aug_24"
I have tried this.

```
str = "week32_Aug_24_2016"
wk = str.split('_')
newstr = wk[0]+" "+wk[3]+" "+wk[1]+" "+wk[2]
```

My expected output is "week32 2016 Aug 24".
I already got that but I want to know is there any better way to do this. Suppose I have long string and no of split value is 10, then this is very long way. So I want to know a better way to arrange the split values. Thanks....

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `long string and no of split value is 10` ?? How could there be more than `4` segments??

Comment: you have two different expected output `week32_2016_Aug_24` and `week32 2016 Aug 24` posted in the question.. do clarify.. and give an example with long string and expected output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of both [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), simply like this:

```
string = "week32_Aug_24_2016"
order = (0, 3, 1, 2)
parts = string.split('_')

new_string = ' '.join(parts[i] for i in order)
```

Also, note that I renamed your variable `str` to `string` to avoid shadowing built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "week32_Aug_24_2016"
wk = str.split('_')
i=0;
newstr="";
while(i<len(wk)):
    newstr=newstr+wk[i]+" "
    i=i+1
print newstr
```

**Something like that. If you want to keep last string in the middle it can be done.**

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "week32_Aug_24_2016"
>>> re.sub(r'_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)', r' \3 \1 \2', string)
'week32 2016 Aug 24'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use str.split() and format() as well:

```
str = "week32_Aug_24_2016"
wk = str.split('_')
newstr = "{} {} {} {}".format(wk[0], wk[3], wk[1], wk[2])
```